# How to remove Ads from Application that uses a library project

Tags: android

Good day, I have a library project that i use to create a paid and free version of an app. Now i don't write any code or have any activity in the different projects except in the library project(for easy maintenance). i have followed the suggestions in the following link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517558/on-android-how-to-use-code-to-distinguish-free-app-vs-paid-app-using-the-same-l)

to try and have an AD free app in the paid app but for some reason the Ads keep coming up.  which could mean some functionalities for the paid won't work either.. What could i be doing wrong? :( do i have to manually copy the Activities from the library project into the project for the paid app and remove the code for the Ads manually and others?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ads have to be initialized somewhere in your library - if nothing else creating the ad view and adding it to the main view. If you want different behavior then you probably want to initialize the library differently - say pass a boolean (or enumeration) to the library at initialization time that the library uses to know whether to invoke the lines of code that create the ad view and add it to the main view. Then your paid app can initialize without ads, while your free app initializes with ads.

Comment: @Colin.. thanks. for some reason, the Ad was still showing even when i commented out the code in the library project. I solved the case by copying the layout with ads into my paid project and just removing the Ads from there. the code was working as expected, as other functionalities were triggered with the paid app; but for some reason, as long as i had the Ad in my xml layout, it was still triggering.

Comment: Ah yes, the XMl layout effectively initializes the ad. In the future you can programmatically create the ad view in your library and then add the view to the outer container in the same place where your current XML is including it. The XMl is not the be-all-end-all definition of the UI - its a great way to layout UIs that don't change, but then you can use Java code to manipulate what was inflated from the XML definition.